# HTML displays duplicates of database entries

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm having an issue with displaying my database entries in HTML.

models.py:

```
class Behandling(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.IntegerField(default=60)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=995)
```

views.py:

```
def behandling(request):
    behandlingar = Behandling.objects.all()
    args = {
        'behandlingar': behandlingar
    }
    return render(request, 'behandlingar.html', args)
```

behandlingar.html

```
<h2>{% for behandling in behandlingar %}
                {{ behandlingar.0.title }}</h2>
              <p>{{ behandlingar.0.description }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
```

[This is what displays in the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0pf3.png)

It seems like the title and description text repeats itself once for each item in the database. What could be wrong?

Comment: `{{ behandlingar.0.title }}` basically means for the 0th indexed object in `behandlingar` render its `title` attribute... Perhaps you wanted to write `{{ behandling.title }}` (and similarly `{{ behandling.description }}`)

Comment: I only want to display one database object per <h2>, the idea is that i can display multiple objects on the page, but in separate html elements. Is there a way to have ```{{ behandlingar.0.title }} ``` to display only one database object?

Answer (score 0):

This way the template would be rendered so one "Behandling" instance would be displayed for each "h2" and "p" tags as you stated in your comment.

```
    {% for behandling in behandlingar %}
        <h2>{{ behandling.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ behandling.description }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```